# Unusual GApps running in background

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-apps, background-data

I was always curious to look into the current running apps in my Android device(running KitKat 4.4.4) and check which app takes up more ram.

As you can see in the screenshot, play music is running even when I'm not listen to songs and Google maps is running for hours when location is turned off (turned off WiFi search for location in advance setting too).

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Because their services are running in the background. It is visible in the screenshot too. Tap an app's entry and you would see what's running of it.

Comment: But my question is why are these services running even when I'm not using music app or map.